# How can a Beta-tester of android applications to have installed both production and beta app in the same device?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, production, beta

I need that my beta testers have the beta app to let them test it but at the same time they must to have the production app to work in production.
The problem is that seems if they become a beta tester only can get the beta app from the Google Play.

There is a way to have both version in the same device without to have to change the app name?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible by design. Beta testers are ideally users who get a slightly earlier version of your app, and use it day to day so you discover issues. The thinking behind this decision was that if you allowed both, then if issues were discovered beta users wouldn't report them, they would just switch to the prod app. Also, as an app developer the beta version should be "production ready" according to your internal QA.

This has value for other reasons. Beta users can't leave public reviews - instead they send private feedback. If you allowed both, then you wouldn't be able to have this feature.

A few well known apps (like Chrome) want users to be able to have both apps. For these apps, they have a separate package name for the Beta version and maintain a separate store listing: [Chrome Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta), [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome).

If you did this it would allow both to be installed. But you would have to maintain two store listings, two sets of reviews etc.

Comment: We actually do this with one of our apps.  We have a second distinct app listing that is a closed beta.  Having a distinct beta app package is also useful if your beta app needs to point to different backend services and your beta builds aren't/can't be directly promoted to prod without changing the build to point at prod services. You can use product flavors to easily define beta and prod configs that build to different package names, point at different service endpoints, etc. And leaving it as a closed beta allows you to worry less about the store listing since the public can't see it.

Comment: Thanks, nice response. I'm not available to do this but to the next project I will consider it. Thanks a lot to the both!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No, it can't be done.

**Update: it turns out the suggestion below is not true...**

But you could sort of achieve this by defining multiple user accounts on the device. Create a second user account on the device that uses a different, not-in-the-beta Google account.  User accounts have their own distinct set of installed apps, so you could then switch between the two user accounts to use the beta or prod app.

Comment: Humm nice, I didn't think in it. But I cannot say to all of my beta-tester that create a new account just for it :(

Comment: Right, it's not terribly convenient. Unfortunately, the Beta app has the same package name as the Prod app and you can only have one installation of any given package per user.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. On android devices there is only one installed version of any given app (shared between accounts). So if one user gets the beta version, all will on that device.

Comment: You know, I think I knew that but clearly forgot it.  For kicks, I just tried it and the results are kind of strange.  When you using the user account that opted into the Beta, the app listing in Play shows you are in the Beta.  When you switch to another account and look at the Play listing, it does not indicate THAT user is in the Beta and the option to join and/or leave the Beta is not displayed.  So the status of the other user(s) on the device is sort of unclear and/or simply not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After some developments after releasing the app to production a bug was reported that I couldn't replicate in the latest version. So I needed to check the production version. As they both have the same name I knew I couldn't have both, so I tried to replace the beta version by the production one.

This is what I found out about how to do it.

Step 1. In my phone I went to the app page but the store insisted to install the beta version.

Step 2. In my phone change the account to one whithout beta test access. The play store detected the other account and installed the beta version.

Step 3. Finnaly I went to the store in my desktop and logged in whith the normal account I have on my device! This worked! The production version was in my phone and I could test it!

So my solution to you is this:

You can't have the two versions simultaneously in the same phone except if they have different names. 
But you can replace the beta by the production one if you have two accounts on the phone and

A) Loggout from the account with access to the beta version and then install the production one,

or

B) Install from a desktop.