# Manage BETA and PRODUCTION app simultaneously for same Account on playstore in android

Tags: android, google-play

I have already app[1.6] in production which I got successfully from play Store. Now I am putting new build[1.7] in BETA with some of enhancement. It becomes live in BETA with 10 -30 minutes.

**Issue** : when I am using email Id for play store which is same in manage tester of console playstore account then I shows only my new enhancement build[1.7]  on playstore but Suppose I am switching my email account for playstore which is not on manage tester account of console playstore then it shows my live build[1.6].

**Question** How can I manage BETA and production app for email Id which is same on playstore [of gmail]and  on manage tester of google console playstore?

Comment: I got answer, thanks a lot. For more info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302839/how-can-a-beta-tester-of-android-applications-to-have-installed-both-production
found on this